# Infimizing an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, supremum-and-infimum, calculus-of-variations

Let $p(t)$ be any continuous increasing function on $[0,\pi/2]$ with $p(0)=0, p(\pi/2)=1$. What is the following infimum?

$$\inf_p \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\left( p'(t) \right)^2}{4p(t) \left(1 - p(t) \right)} \, {\rm d} t$$

It seems that we could not estimate

$$p(t) \left(1 - p(t) \right) \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

since the minimum could not be attained.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{p'^2(t)}{4p(t)[1-p(t)]}dt=\int_0^1 [(\sqrt{p(t)})'^2+(\sqrt{1-p(t)})'^2]dt$$

But we could not use the Schwarz inequality to estimate from below, since if the equality occurs, $p$ is a linear funtion,

Comment: Do you assume that $p$ is everywhere differentiable?

Comment: @ArcticChar Monotonic functions are differentiable almost everywhere. Thus one can speak of $p'$ even though $p$ is only continuous.

Comment: Firstly, you can get rid of the 4 in the denominator. Then, how about applying quadratic-arithmetic integral inequality, calculate the value and solve the differential equation for which the equality holds?

Comment: I mean $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{p'(t)^2}{p(t)(1 - p (t))} \geq \frac{\left( \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{p'(t)}{\sqrt{p(t)(1 - p(t))}} \right)^2}{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ The value of the last integral can be calculated with a change of variable

Comment: If your only restrictions are continuity and monotonicity, then you can plug in the Cantor staircase function to see that the infimum is zero.

Comment: @Jake28 Why does the change of variable fails?

Comment: @Jorge change of variable is applicable only for some functions (I guess absolute continuity suffices), and the Cantor staircase does not meet that criteria. (Of course we still need the OP to tell us the assumptions)